# random seed fails to reproduce run in NetLogo when selecting breed-neighbors

Tags: netlogo

I have a network with three undirected link breeds

```
undirected-link-breed [ parentals parental ]
undirected-link-breed [ diffusions diffusion ]
undirected-link-breed [ simdiffusions simdiffusion ]
```

I have have fixed the seed and run my go procedure calling different procedures that always reproduce the output, as expected given the seed. My go procedure simply selects a turtle and then this turtle execute one of the available procedures. None of these procedures calls anything link-related. Everything works and I can reproduce a run given a seed, so I am quite confident that the code works.

I then have a last procedure that, when selected, breaks the random sequence and fails to reproduce the output across different runs. This time the calling turtle selected in GO calls the procedure below:

```
to network-mechanisms
    ;; THIS LINE BREAKS THE RNG
    let innovator-nei parental-neighbors with [typeof = "potter"]
    ;; THIS LINE DOES NOT BREAK THE RNG
    ;let innovator-nei other turtles with [typeof = "potter"]
    ask innovator-nei [
        let my-nei parental-neighbors with [typeof = "potter"]
        if any? my-nei [
            set attribute sum [centrality] of my-nei with [adopted-now?] / count my-nei
            set attribute 1 / (1 + exp (4 - 8 * attribute))
        ]
    ]
    ask innovator-nei [
        if random-float 1 < attribute [
            adopt
            create-simdiffusion-with myself [set color red]
        ]
    ]
end
```

If the calling turtle looks for its parental-neighbors, then something strange happens and the RNG sequence changes at every run, no matter the seed; while if the calling turtle calls all other turtles, then the RNG sequence is identical across runs... Is this a known problem when working with link-breeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such known problem. If you think you've found a bug, please open a ticket at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/new and include a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). (The above code is not self-contained — you don't include the necessary declarations, and you don't include the code you used to test and reproduce the bug — and it also doesn't appear to be the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem.)

Here's an example of what a SSCCE for this issue might look like:

```
undirected-link-breed [parentals parental]
turtles-own [typeof]

to setup
  clear-all
  crt 5 [ create-parentals-with other turtles ]
  ask n-of 3 turtles [ set typeof "potter" ]
  ask turtles [
    let innovator-nei parental-neighbors with [typeof = "potter"]
  ]
  print random-float 1.0
end

to test
  random-seed 0
  setup
  random-seed 0
  setup
end
```

As it happens, this code doesn't show any bug; when run, it prints the same number twice, which is the correct behavior:

```
observer> test
0.8700121472788938
0.8700121472788938
```

But it shows what would be needed in order to file a proper bug report.

Comment: I am trying to replicate the inconsistency I have found, as soon as I have it, I'll file a bug report. Good to know there is no issues with link breeds I should be aware of. Thanks

Comment: just to let you know, nothing's wrong with NetLogo, if I build a fake network inside NetLogo, everything works fine with my code, but if I try to import a graphml from my own extension then the problem occurs. I will report back in the nw bug [here](https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension/issues/144) - I tried to import the graphml on my own since the problem in nw:load-graphml...